# Could not code sign a Mac App

Tags: swift, macos, provisioning-profile, xcode7.3, macos-sierra

I successfully submitted my app [ version 1.0 ] to `iTunesConnect` for review. And they have rejected it because I have added an extra `App Sandbox feature`. So I solved that thing and tried to archive my project in new build number.

Also I have selected my `Code Signing Identity 3rd Party Mac Developer Application`, And came back to Project Settings -> General, now I could see that the Signing switched to `None` and `Team` automatically changed to None. So I have changed that to `My Team Name` and Signing into `Mac App Store`. Now I have went back to `Project Settings -> Build Setting`s, There the code signing identity has different identity selected [  `Two Mac Developer & One 3rd Party Mac Developer` ].

So what happens is that whenever I change something the opposite happen in other place. Basically I am unable to archive my project cause of code signing issue.

If I try to code sign using `Mac Developer` Identity, it shows me something that I never seen before.

Something like `error: A cryptographic verification failure has occurred`. 

`*** error: Couldn't codesign /Users/Alvin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bjtynsmrmxhrfffdvpfwxeanbgkb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1`

So how will I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

By the way, I am using `Xcode 7.3.1` in `macOS Sierra`. Is that can be a problem? No right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there may be code signing issues with macOS Sierra. You can follow the issue [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48637).

I would recommend reverting back to El Cap and only installing an early beta of a new Mac OS on a machine used for testing the OS, not one you are doing active development on.

**[update 7/6/2016]**

Some developers are reporting this fixed with macOS Sierra Beta 2 and Xcode 8 Beta 2, but I have not yet comfirmed on my spare Mac if this fixes the problem.

Also, some developers have reported that resetting the Keychain fixes is. In the Keychain Access app , go to "Preferences..." and click "Reset My Default Keychain".

Comment: There's not much useful information at that link you provided.

Comment: The link was provided to validate that it is a known macOS Sierra issue that others are having / reporting. I guess my point is there is a known issue with the new **BETA** OS the user is using, specifically related to the thing they are trying to do.  If Apple fixes it, the link on Apple's developer site would be a good place to follow for updates.  In the meantime, as my answer states, put El Cap back on the Mac they are using for their **PRODUCTION** app store builds.  My advice is correct and will almost certainly fix their problem.