# getting errors with Xcode 8: "A cryptographic verification failure has occurred."

Tags: provisioning-profile, xcode8

At first I was getting an error that involved my signing identity. After signing out and then signing back in, I'm now getting the following errors. I think it has something to do with the the certificates or provisioning profile.

> error: A cryptographic verification failure has occurred.
>   *** error: Couldn't codesign /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SeedDemo-elhrfqwwnjtcgucmplbbubsbcjcd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SeedDemo.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib:
>   codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you update to macOS Sierra? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48637

Comment: I did. Do you have any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like there is a code signing problem that is affecting people who upgraded to Sierra.  Can you revert back to El Cap?  I don't know of any known solutions, but a Radar has been submitted.

Comment: I gave a bit more information in another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826242/could-not-code-sign-a-mac-app/37883303#37883303), but it was deleted.  I re-answered it and was down-voted, so apparently responding that something is a known bug with no known workarounds is frowned upon. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a macOS Sierra problem that is affecting many other developers.  Your options now are to revert back to El Cap, or to wait and hope for a resolution with the next Sierra / Xcode 8 beta.  I wish there was a better answer, but at this time (6/26/2016), those are the only know solutions.

Some developers are reporting this fixed with macOS Sierra Beta 2 and Xcode 8 Beta 2, but I have not yet comfirmed on my spare Mac if this fixes the problem.

Also, some developers have reported that resetting the Keychain fixes is. In the `Keychain Access` app , go to "Preferences..." and click "Reset My Default Keychain".